# Last Digit of the Sum of Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

I want to calculate the last digit of a sum of Fibonacci numbers:
$F_{m} + F_{m + 1} + \cdots + F_{n}$.

- $m$ and $n$ are $2$ non-negative integers and $m \leq n$.
- I have one sample input with output $m = 10, n=10\ \mbox{and}\ o/p = 5$, which I don't understand.
- Because if I do sum $F_{10} + F_{10} = 55 + 55 = 110$. So the last digit is 0. I don't get the part that the answer is $5$.

Comment: When $m=n$ there is just one term in the sum, $F_m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum $a_m + \ldots + a_n$, when $m = n$, is just $a_m$. One term. So in your case, $F_m + \ldots + F_n$ for $m = n = 10$ is $F_{10} = 55$.